# How do I solve the issue "can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'" in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

```
string = (input("Input a string of random chars! "))
multi = int(len(string))
multi1 = float(multi)
print(multi)
print(("-") * round((multi * 10),1))
print("|", ("_") * round((multi1/2),1), "|")
```

Comment: `len()` returns an integer, why do you need to call `int()`?

Comment: Why are you using a `float` as the multiplier? What do you expect to get if there's a fraction?

Comment: If the string is 11 characters long, `multi1/2` will be `5.5`. How can you make 5.5 copies of the sequence `("_")`?

Comment: you cant multiply `str` with `float`, can do with `int` type, as @Barmar said cant make a string fraction(`float`) times.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? It maybe simpler with `str.format()`.

Answer (score 1):

you need `int` to repeat the string

```
print("|", ("_") * int(round((multi1/2),1)), "|")
```